# remove current page url for href in my website

Tags: html, model-view-controller

@list.LinkName

@list.LinkUrl contains value "www.google.com" but it is showing localhost/www.google.com I need just href="www.google.com"
[image: image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your href to add the http in front

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">1</a>
```